# Magento 2 How to add two different label in checkout page

Tags: checkout, extra

I want to display two custom label in checkout page above the order total but confused in html and js files. Labels are loads dynamically from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it my self that by using **knockout js foreach loop**, multiple labels you can display.